# call a perl function on click of a button and fill the return value into a textfield in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, perl, cgi, textfield

I'm completely new to the HTML, javascript & web world. My requirement is as follows.

## UI layout

```
username:   __________ |find button|
First name: __________
Last name:  __________
e-mail:     __________
```

## To be done

1. user enters a user name in the username textfield & clicks on find button
2. On click of find button, call the Perl method `getDetails("enteredUName")`
3. Capture the return value from the called Perl method and fill the details in the remaining textfields (first, last names & email).

I've the form and the searching logic ready.

Now my confusion is what should I put in the `-onClick` attribute of the **search** button. In the code, for forms, there's always javascript calls written for other buttons. So how should I make a call to the Perl method upon click of the search button and fill the remain text fields?

### Update

Based on my current understanding did the following:

1. Defined a hidden boolean parameter `isUsernameGiven`, with initial value 0, in the form
2. When user types something in textfield with name `usernameText` and clicks search button, invoke javascript which sets the value of `isUsernameGiven` to 1 and the window location with a specified action.
3. Action is routed to the Perl module file via the application perl script. In this module, the search happens based on `usernameText` parameter
4. Newly appearing form comes with the details pre-filled.

### Code Structure

```
ApplicationDirectory
  application.pl
    ModuleFolder
        ModuleFile.pm

application.pl:
    ...
    if ($action eq 'save') {
        my $m = new ModuleFile();
    }
    ...


ModuleFile.pm:
    ...
    sub new {
        # param isUsernameGiven is preserved/carried over from previous??
        my $isUsernameGiven = param('isUsernameGiven');
        if ($isUsernameGiven != 0) {
            param(-name=>'isUsernameGiven',-value=>$isUsernameGiven);
        }
        if ( $action eq "add" ) {
            showAddForm($self);
        } elsif ($action eq "addEmp") {
            showAddForm($self, $self->getUserInfoFromActiveDir(param('usernameText')));
        }
    }
    sub getUserInfoFromActiveDir {
        # search info and return employee object
        ...
    }
    sub showForm {
        ...
        print "\n<form name=\"edit_employee_form\" method=\"post\" action=\"application.pl\" onSubmit=\"return validate_form();\">\n";
        print "<input type='hidden' name='isUsernameGiven' value='0'/>\n";

        print "<table class=edit style=\"width:420px;\">\n";
        my $findButton = '';
        if (!$id) {
            $findButton = "<td>\n".button(-value=>"Find", -class=>"bigbutton",
                -onClick=>"document.edit_employee_form.isUsernameGiven.value=1;getDetailsFilled();")."</td>";
        }
        my $fieldname = 'username';
        print "<tr><td>Username:</td><td > \n".textfield(-name=>$fieldname -default=$unameValue,".
            "-size=>30, -maxlength=>50)."</td>".$findButton."</tr><br>";

        print "<tr><td>First Name:</td><td > \n".textfield(-name=>'first', -default=>$fnameValue, -size=>30, -maxlength=>50)."</td></tr>\n";
        print "<tr><td class=edit>Last Name:</td><td > \n".textfield(-name=>'name', -default=$lnameValue, -size=>30, -maxlength=>50)."</td></tr>\n";
        ...
    }

ModuleFile.js:
    ...
    function getDetailsFilled()
    {
        if ( document.edit_employee_form.username.value == "" )
        {
            alert ( "Please fill in a username." );
            document.edit_item_form.username.focus();
        } else {
            // Call Perl method here
            window.location="application.pl?application=ModuleFile&action=addEmp";
        }
    }
    ...
```

## Problem

1. Upon clicking the find button nothing happens. What did I miss?
2. Seems the parameter `isUsernameGiven` is coming as undefined in the sub `showform`.

   1. Do the param values get preserved or reset for every `ModuleFile` object?
   2. How's the value coming as undefined if the default value of `isUsernameGiven` is set to 0?
   3. Is my understanding of params correct?
3. Is my current overall approach correct?

Comment: Are you automating a browser? If so, see https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize and/or https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Chrome . Otherwise, you will have to learn how [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) works. In either case, you will have to learn Javascript in addition to Perl.

Comment: no automation here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: If you want to write a website where you can write the client code in Perl, consider looking at [WebPerl](https://webperl.zero-g.net/) , which allows you to run Perl on the client in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without involving Javascript (well, you probably could, but 99.9% of your users will have browsers that can only use Javascript for client-side programming).

You need to do it like this:

- Set up a Javascript event handler on your find button which grabs the username value and makes an AJAX call to your web server, including the username.
- Write an AJAX handler sitting on your web server which takes the username, calls your code, formats the data as JSON and returns that data to the browser.
- Set up Javascript in the web page that takes the JSON returned from the AJAX call, extracts the various data items and inserts them into the appropriate part of the page.